# NSFileManager works fine on simulator but not on device

Tags: device, nsfilemanager, createfile

I have problem creating directories and files with NSFileManager on the iPhone device.
My code, shown below, works fine on the simulator, but not on the device, could you please help me? Gimme some directions where the problem may be, thanks for every reply..

I'm first creating directories this way:

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *arPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appPath = [[NSString alloc] init];
appPath = [arPaths objectAtIndex:0];

strDownloadsDir = [[NSString alloc] init];
strDownloadsDir = [[appPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Other"] copy];
if(![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:strDownloadsDir])
    [fileMgr createDirectoryAtPath:strDownloadsDir attributes:nil];
```

and then I'm trying to create new file in this directory this way:

```
NSString *filePath = [strDownloadsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strDlFileName];
//Test whether this file exists, if not, create it
NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
if(![fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    if([fileMgr createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil])
        NSLog(@"Creating new file at path %@", filePath);
    else
        NSLog(@"Failed to create new file.");
}
```

It seems that there's something wrong with whole NSFileManager, because when I'm using fileExistAtPath with a path given by this

```
NSArray *arPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appPath = [[NSString alloc] init];
appPath = [arPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

it is not working too, I tried to change directory to NSDocumentsDirectory but it did not help

Comment: You're leaking a lot of NSStrings. Don't do unnecessary `[[NSString alloc] init];`.

Answer (score 1):

may be because the use of method " createDirectoryAtPath: attrubutes: " is DEPRECATED by apple.....

Answer (score 0):

You only can create file under the sandbox directory of your application. Apple will not permit you create file out of that.

Is that the reason you failed on your phone ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:strPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *strFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hello/config.plist"];
        NSLog(@"strFile: %@", strFile);

        NSString *strPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hello"];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:strPath]) {
            NSLog(@"there is no Directory: %@",strPath);
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:strPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        }

        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"username", @"password", @"serverName", @"serverPort", @"autoSave", nil];
        NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"11", @"11", @"11", @"11", @"11", nil];

        NSDictionary *configInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: values forKeys:keys];
        if (![configInfo writeToFile: strFile atomically: YES]) {
            NSLog(@"write file error");
        }
```